# Send an image in the body of the mail using any of the mail utilities in Linux

Tags: mutt, sendmail, mailx

I am trying to send an email from Linux server, I want to send an image, not as an attachment, that should be displayed in the message body.

I tried.

```
mailx -s "TEST mail" <MASKED>@mask.com < download.JPEG
```

The above command gave a random junk data in the body of the mail

```
mailx --append "Content-type: text/html" -s "TEST mail" <MASKED>@mask.com < download.JPEG
```

The above command didn't work

```
mutt -a "download.JPEG" <MASKED>@mask.com -s "TEST mail" < /dev/null
```

The above command sent the image as an attachment.

`UUENCODE` is not installed in our server, so we shouldn't use the same.

I don't want anyone of the above. I want my picture to be displayed on the body of my mail instead.

Any help on this is highly appreciated.

Comment: It is not recommended sending it in raw binary. I actually prefer `mpack` to `uuencode`. Install it.

Answer (score 3):

To get the picture to be displayed in-line, it must be encoded as a valid MIME object with a `Content-Disposition: inline` header in it.

The `mpack` command can do this.

Try sending an email like this:

```
mpack -s "TEST mail" -c image/jpeg download.JPEG <MASKED>@example.com
```

Or if you want to output the result into a file instead of sending it directly:

```
mpack -s "TEST mail" -c image/jpeg download.JPEG -o email-with-image.txt
```

Then you can send it later with e.g.:

```
mailx <MASKED>@example.com < email-with-image.txt
```

If you want to add text to your message before the image, write it into a file, and add a `-d text-before.txt` option to the `mpack` command. For adding text after the image, just appending it to the mpack-produced file should work.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the below command.

#### Command

```
mutt -e "set content_type=text/html" -a lb.png -s "Test Mail" user@example.com < mail.html
```

#### mail.htm

```
<img src="cid:lb.png" />
```

Reference: [Display attached image in email body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16857588/display-attached-image-in-email-body)

Comment: Can't stat user@example.com: No such file or directory
user@example.com: unable to attach file.
same with any other email address. Mutt 1.5.21 (2010-09-15)

Comment: I have: Can't stat my@email.com: No such file or directory  too

Comment: The recipient should come before options like this:  mutt user@example.com -e "set content_type=text/html" -a lb.png -s "Test Mail"  < mail.html

Answer (score 0):

[sendimagemail](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/tkkcc/dot/master/home/bilabila/bin/scripts/sendimagemail) is  a 100 line bash wrapper for `sendmail`([msmtp](https://marlam.de/msmtp/) implement), which supports sending multiple jpg/png/gif inline images and text to gmail/outlook/qq/163 services. Here is the manual.

```bsh
sendimagemail dst [image...] [--cc=''] [--bcc=''] [--subject='20210315 00:33:52'] [--body=''] [--dry] -- [sendmail-option]

# send text/html to one or more residents, with Cc and Bcc
sendimagemail bilabila@qq.com --body='Hi bilabila' --subject='Hi bilabila'
sendimagemail bilabila@qq.com --body='<div style=color:lightslategray>Hi bilabila<div/>'
sendimagemail 'qq bilabila@qq.com, google bilabila@gmail.com' --cc='163 bilabila@163.com' --bcc='ms bilabila@live.com'

# send one or more images
sendimagemail bilabila@qq.com a.jpg
sendimagemail bilabila@qq.com --body='<div>images</div>' a.jpg b.png c.gif

# send with non-default account
sendimagemail bilabila@qq.com a.jpg -- -a google
sendimagemail bilabila@qq.com a.jpg -- --from=bilabila@qq.com --host=smtp.qq.com --user=bilabila --passwordeval='echo TOKEN' --port 587 --auth --tls
sendimagemail bilabila@qq.com a.jpg -- --from=bilabila@163.com --host=smtp.163.com --user=bilabila@163.com --passwordeval='echo TOKEN' --port 25 --auth --tls
sendimagemail bilabila@qq.com a.jpg -- --from=bilabila@gmail.com --host=smtp.gmail.com --user=bilabila@gmail.com --passwordeval='echo TOKEN' --port 587 --auth --tls

# show what would be sent
sendimagemail bilabila@qq.com a.jpg --dry
```